# (in your hand) or (with your hand)

Tags: prepositions

(1a) I am holding a 2-meter flag **in** my hand.

(1b) I am holding a 2-meter flag **with** my hand.

(2a) You are holding a pack of gum **in** your hand.

(2b) You are holding a pack of gum **with** your hand.

I am not sure which preposition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In both your examples, *in* would be appropriate (the object is being supported by the hand). You hold something *with* your hand if you are using the hand to keep the object steady in a certain position.

*He held the nail in place with his left hand while he reached for the hammer.*

Comment: You could also hold a flag in place with your hand - especially a 2-metre one. The flag is held up by the ground and you're stopping it from falling over.